# Proguard with Crashlytics

Tags: android, proguard, crashlytics, android-proguard, crashlytics-android

We have added [crashlytics](/questions/tagged/crashlytics) in our android application, and we are using `proguard`. So, as the `crashlytics` documentation says, we have added the following code in our `proguard` configuration file:

```
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable *Annotation*
```

Unfortunately, when we sign the APK, we get the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Unknown option '*Annotation*'
```

What are we doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: missing comma between LIneNumberTable and *ANnotation*

Comment: You are right, a comma was missing and that was the reason of my error. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This ProGuard rules

```
# Crashlytics
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*
-keep class com.crashlytics.android.**
```

And please make sure that `,`s are in place.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems that there's an error in crashlytics's documentation, and a comma was missing. Adding ',' solved my error. Thank you very much!